# C++ destructor not working as intended

Tags: c++

I'm writing an operating system in C++. I do not have the std libs at my disposal (so I'm not sure if this works normally with std libs). It appears that if I `delete` an object, it only calls the destructor of the variable type (and it's parents).

For example:

```
Aa* aa = new Bb();
delete aa;
```

will only print "destructing Aa". Whereas

```
Bb* bb = new Bb();
delete bb;
```

will print both "destructing Bb" and "destructing Aa".

I tried to work around this issue by calling the sub class destructor in the super class destructor (as seen below).

Is there something I'm missing here, or will I have to resort to casting to the concrete type before the initial `delete`?

```
class Aa {
public:
    ~Aa();
};
class Bb : public Aa {
public:
    ~Bb() {
        log("destructing Bb");
    }
};

Aa::~Aa() {
    log("destructing Aa");

    // TODO checks if we are of type Bb
    // ((Bb*) this)->~Bb(); // uncomment to test calling sub class destructor
}
```

Comment: Aren't you forgetting the `virtual` keyword somewhere?

Comment: "Is there something I'm missing here" - Yes. `virtual` destructors when deleting via base object pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make the destructor of `Aa` virtual:

```
class Aa {
public:
    virtual ~Aa();
};
```

This is a basic concept of c++. You can read on it [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-37/) (and in many other places).

Comment: I do not have access to the std lib so virtual functions do not work.

Comment: @chris13524 vitrual defination is not part of the std lib, it's integral part of the language

Comment: I had to add the `-fno-rtti` flag to `gcc` and now it works (still requires `virtual`).

Answer (score 0):

Your "Aa" destructor is not virtual, so what you are observing is the expected behaviour.

To get the behaviour *you* expect, declare the destructor as `virtual ~Aa() = default;` .